# SceneKit shader modifier is not modifying the geometry's position

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit

I am trying to apply a simple shader modifier to move the position of the cube. The regular diffuse color of the cube is a light blue, but with this modifier is does turn red, so I know the shader modifier is working (somewhat). However, the cube remains in the center of the screen at the position (0,0,0), so the position is not being modified by the shader modifier. Any ideas?

Here is the code

```
          let modifier = """
          _surface.diffuse = float4(1,0,0,1);
          _surface.position = float3(10.0,0.0,0.0);
          """
          
          cube.geometry?.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.surface : modifier]
```

Answer (score -1):

The magenta tint is SceneKit's way to indicate that a shader has failed to compile.

> `_surface.position = float3(10.0,0.0,0.0);`

Looking at SCNShadable.h we see that `SCNShaderSurface`'s `position` is a `float4`, not a `float3`.

Comment: I think you're mistaken, it is indeed a float3 by the pasted in snippet (and I also just checked myself)

Comment: it's a `float3` in your code but SceneKit expects a `float4`, see SCNShadable.h

Comment: this is what I see in the `_surface` struct in `SCNShadable.h` - 

`float3 position;    // Position of the fragment`